# How to create a REST service for an android app that uses a MySQL database?

Tags: android, mysql, rest

Previously I've used Firebase for my database but now I'm using MySQL for a project. I have no idea how to create a REST service and to connect my Android app to my MySQL database. Are there any resources with sample code I can look at?

Comment: You could use [openshift](https://openshift.io/) to host a webservice using a variety of containers. Since you have done an android app Java would probably be a good choice. Here is a simple Rest project done in Java that connects to a MySQL database that I was able to deploy to a Tomcat container in openshift. [sample project](https://github.com/Crash-Test-Buddies/DataCollectorService)

Answer (score 0):

You can try any server language like java, php that return data from mysql server in rest format. It is easy to develop api in php.
Have a look into http://phppot.com/php/rest-api-crud-using-php/ for basic crud operation.